# Divs with the content of modal dialogs are visible before the DOM loads

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

in my application I have a rather large table, which takes some time to load.

There I have several [Jquery UI modal dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form):

```
    $( "#element_copy" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 550,
        modal: true,
        close: function() { 
            $(":checked").removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
```

Dialogs work fine.

**PROBLEM:**

Before the whole table and everything is loaded, on the bottom of the window you can see all the divs of the modal windows. How would you prevent this?

Comment: make sure you have style="display:none" on element with id element_copy

Comment: If you asked me an hour ago I'd swear I'd tried this :))

Hereby I thank all of you guys with a +1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the dialogs in your CSS:

```
#element_copy, #another_dialog, #yet_another {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set them to display:none (through a style attribute or a common css class).
Upon using dialog('open'), they will be shown once again.

Answer (score 1):

Use css to hide all your elements